# Gaining fat for muscles-stomach fat

Tags: workout-routines

i was doing workouts when i was slim i didn't get enough visible results.What i did 6 mounths was ,to cut the workouts for 6 mounths until now and start food intake so i will add fat on my self.I obtain fat,i eat a lot of from then,meaning  i get  8kg more.If i start now again workouts i will gain faster visible results?example my biceps will be more visible because now i have fat on my organism because then i hadnt?The problem is the most of the fat i gain is  in stomach.I don't know if my thought was right.My question is,now i have fat on stomach mainly,will in 2-3mounths my biceps be seemed?
More informations:In past in 3mounths my gain wasn't good enough because i didn't have fat.I want to say that i was a slim and i manage it to be more than normal body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to ask but you will gain fat all around your body during a bulking phase. Thus, fat gain on stomach is all normal.
However, If you're gaining too much fat then you're eating at too much of a caloric surplus that is actually required so cut back on some calories a bit and make sure you're eating just 300-500 calories above your maintenance.
Because you didn't mention your current goals, current stats, workout routines, cardiovascular conditioning etc. so I can't provide you with a specific guideline.